# Azure B2C custom policy claims transformation using FormatStringMultipleClaims with default value if claim is NULL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, claims

was wandering if someone knows how to use default values in a claims transformation?
If I have the following code:

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">  
    <InputClaims>  
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />  
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />  
    </InputClaims>  
    <InputParameters>  
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0} {1}" />  
    </InputParameters>  
    <OutputClaims>  
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />  
    </OutputClaims>  
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

If a 'surname' was not supplied, the signup will fail.

I have tried adding DefaultValue to input claims, but it will not upload with an XML parsing error.

Also tried a claims transformation to create a string claim with DefaultValue. but again, it would not upload.

Am kind of running out of ideas, search engines do not give me any hints and I cannot be the first person to have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution.
I was able to add a default value to the technical profile that uses the claims transformation.

```
     <TechnicalProfile Id="Validate-DisplayName">
        <DisplayName>Validate displayName</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <InputClaims>
           <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
           <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" DefaultValue="" /> <!-- keep default value as empty!! otherwise signup will fail because surname is null -->
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaimsTransformations>
           <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" />
        </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
     </TechnicalProfile>
```